# Better sanity check for JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript

So, I have a modular component... meaning it might appear in multiple applications. These are all internal, so the component's behaviour can "grow" as we add more products.

Overall, there are probably better designs to accomplish what I want to accomplish, but in the interest of fast development, I was doing this:

```
function someFunc(opt) {
  if(typeof(taEnvironment) !== "undefined")) {
    if(taEnvironment === "webApp") {
      // do stuff when a variable taEnvironment exists and its value is "webapp"
    }
  }
}
```

It's tedious to do this every time I need to check on "webApp", so I want to abstract it a LITTLE bit. The proposed refactor looks a bit like this:

```
function someFunc(opt) {
  if(environment("webApp")) {
      // do stuff when a variable taEnvironment exists and its value is "webapp"
  }
}

//...elsewhere in the same module...
function environment(env) {
  var envSet = false;
  if(typeof(env) === "undefined") {
    return envSet;
  }
  if(typeof(taEnvironment) !== "undefined")) {
    if(taEnvironment === env) {
      envSet = true;
  }
  return envSet;
}
```

2-part question:

1. Even just looking at the first non-refactored snippet; is this the usual way to check for such variables? You can't combine the typeof check with a value check because if it's undefined you will get a failure on the value check. So first I check typeof for "undefined" and then nested inside, I check for the value. It SEEMS like the only way to do this, but if there's a better pattern, I'm all ears!
2. Depending on the answer to #1 -- if #1 is a reasonable or expected way of doing things, does the proposed refactor make sense? Or am I not creating any significant efficiencies?

Comment: I take it you have some usage for this where you aren't passing a literal string, and `env` can actually be `undefined`.

Comment: Even though it sounds like you don't know where `taEnvironment` will be declared, I would still declare it in an outermost closure that contains all the code if at all possible. The `typeof foo === "undefined"` hack is just too painful and can almost always be avoided. I mean if you can create a function in the same scope like the answers show below, why can't you just do `var taEnvironment;` instead?

Comment: var taEnvironment gets declared inside the individual application somewhere. The sanity check is for projects in which a taEnvironment is not needed; then the developer doesn't necessarily need to declare one. The taEnvironment being declared is to be considered optional. @crush: not really. It's probably overkill. ;)

Comment: @GregPettit Disregard. I somehow overlooked that you were checking to see if `taEnvironment` has been *declared* vs *defined*. I'm so used to using an IIFE that ensures it is declared: `(function (taEnvironment) { })(window.taEnvironment = window.taEnvironment || {});` that I never have to worry about if it's declared (or even undefined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense, although there are some steps you can take to make it easier on future generations.

When a reusable function returns a Boolean, you can make that obvious by putting the function in the form of a question, such as `isEnvironment(x)` instead of just the ambiguous `environment(x)`

You can also simplify the function itself by just returning the evaluation of the condition `taEnvironment === env` instead of setting a variable and then returning that variable.

Here's a cleaned up version of your function:

```
function isEnvironment(env) {
  if(typeof taEnvironment === "undefined") {
    return false;
  }else{
    return taEnvironment === env; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check for all conditions at the same time. The `&&` operator will stop at the first `false` result:

```
function environment(env) {
    return typeof taEnvironment !== 'undefined' &&
           taEnvironment === env;
}
```

Comment: This `typeof env !== 'undefined' &&` is unnecessary. The parameter is definitely declared, and if the first `!==` test passes, then if `taEnvironment === env` also passes, you automatically know that `env` was not `undefined`.

Comment: Super clean. I like that it's a simple one-line return. This answer has taught me something about efficient code. I'm ultimately still going with explicit condition check but I for sure got something out of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

> is this the usual way to check for such variables?

Yep.

> does the proposed refactor make sense?

Yes. You could also use a `try...catch`, but that's really up to you:

```
function environment(env) {
  try {
    return typeof env !== 'undefined' && taEnvironment === env;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

Note: `typeof` is not a function, it's an operator.

Comment: I would be embarrassed to tell you how many times I've treated typeof as a function... I must have done it once a few years ago and it worked (the parentheses are just irrelevant) so I just did it that way ever since... Thanks for your answer and also the try/catch suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I have recently also gotten mileage out of hasOwnProperty when the "variable" I want to check isn't a discrete variable in and of itself, but is rather an expected property of an object.

So, given some sort of flag object:

```
flags = {
  appStarted: true,
  userAuthenticated: true
}
```

I might have need to see if the user has done something. I could either initialize the object to have `thingDone: false` and then check for truth in my conditional; or I could simply not initialize with a default and check to see if it has been set:

`if (flags.hasOwnProperty("thingDone")`

This answer is outside the scope of the original question (which was specifically about checking variables), but it may prove useful to someone who would have otherwise been checking on `if(typeof flags.thingDone === "undefined")`. It's six of one and half-dozen of the other (ie the same thing) but I find it more personally semantically meaningful. Your mileage may vary.